# Type level mapping over a HList

Tags: scala, mapping, shapeless, type-level-computation, hlist

I am handrolling my database API and would essentially like to model column families as a `HList` of columns, with the latter loosely being a `Seq[_]`, so somewhere I have a type like `Column[String]::Column[Int]::Column[Double]::HNil`, with all elements sharing a common type constructor.

What would be the simplest way of expressing the type of rows, ie `String::Int::Double::HNil`, from the type given above, essentially unwrapping the inner types?
My current reasoning is that since shapeless can do a map over that `HList` given the right `poly`, one should be able to (ab)use the depedent type `Out` of the `Mapper` trait.

One thing I can think of is just implementing a useless `poly` with the right cases, like a `Case.Aux[Column[T],T]` for all `T`s then summon a `Mapper` for it et voilá, there I have my `Out`, but this feels a bit hacky and I'm not sure it would even work.
On the other hand, I do not yet feel that comfortable around dependent types and type recursion to really want to try and implement something which shapeless obviously already does.

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import shapeless.PolyDefns.~>
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Comapped, NatTRel}
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, Id}

object App {
  case class Column[A](a: A)

  def extract[L <: HList, L1 <: HList](l: L)(implicit
    comapped: Comapped.Aux[L, Column, L1],
    natTRel: NatTRel[L, Column, L1, Id],
  ): L1 = natTRel.map(new (Column ~> Id) { def apply[T](col: Column[T]) = col.a }, l)

  val result = extract(Column(1) :: Column("a") :: HNil)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(result) // 1 :: a :: HNil
  }
}
```

or

```
import shapeless.PolyDefns.~>
import shapeless.ops.hlist.NatTRel
import shapeless.{HList, HNil}

object App {
  case class Column[A](a: Seq[A])

  def extract[L <: HList, L1 <: HList](l: L)(implicit
    natTRel: NatTRel[L, Column, L1, Seq],
  ): L1 = natTRel.map(new (Column ~> Seq) { def apply[T](col: Column[T]): Seq[T] = col.a }, l)

  val result = extract(Column(Seq("a", "b")) :: Column(Seq(1, 2)) :: Column(Seq(10.0, 20.0)) :: HNil)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(result) // List(a, b) :: List(1, 2) :: List(10.0, 20.0) :: HNil
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just so that I understand what is happening here: I am taking a natural transformation and transform (map?) whatever type constructor (column? effect? functor?) I have to the Identity type (monad? functor? effect?) with the help of a few cryptic implicits that one should be able to decipher from the docs and the computation results in the right type? Guess today is just as good to start learning some deep shapeless magic as any other day.